# Different results of xstring test with inputenc and fontspec

Tags: fontspec, input-encodings, xstring

In the following MWE both tests are true on `pdflatex` and `inputenc` but the second test fails on `fontspec` and `luatex`/`xelatex`. Any chance to get this engine agnostic (both true)?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[logonly]{trace}\traceon
\usepackage{xstring}


\begin{document}

ß in Maß: \IfSubStr{Maß}{ß}{TRUE}{FALSE}%
\newline%
\ss{} in Maß: \IfSubStr{Maß}{\ss}{TRUE}{FALSE}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: `ß ` is not an active char with luatex/xetex.  You could change this, but why do you want to do it?

Comment: The idea was to restrict package code to us-ascii.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that both tests with `pdflatex` return true is essentially a lucky coincidence.

The package `xstring` performs *full* expansion to the tokens in (some of) its arguments (see the package documentation); in the case of `\IfSubStr` the first and second arguments are fully expanded.

What happens to `ß` in `pdflatex` is:

1. `ß` is actually two bytes in UTF-8;
2. the first byte, `0xC3` makes TeX examine the next one, `0x9F` and transform both according to an internal table to `\ss` (in `utf8enc.dfu` you find `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DF}{\ss}`);
3. according to the current output encoding (here `T1`), `\ss` is transformed into `\T1\ss` (a quite strange token) which is internally defined through `\chardef` so it is unexpandable.

Thus you see that the same happens when you type `\ss`, just jumping over some of the above steps.

When `lualatex` is used, `ß` undergoes no expansion at all, because `lualatex` directly reads UTF-8 and internally transforms it into (abstract) Unicode. On the other hand, `\ss` becomes `\TU\ss` (similar to the above), which is essentially equivalent to type `` \char`ß `` (so it's *not* the same as typing `ß`).

Try `\IfSubStr{Ș}{Ș}{TRUE}{FALSE}` with `pdflatex` and you'll get a low level error

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@xs@arg@ii.
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.15 \IfSubStr{Ș}{Ș}
                      {TRUE}{FALSE}
```

No error with `lualatex`.

There's no guarantee of success when `\IfSubStr` is used for non ASCII characters.